# online linear regression with forgetting

Tags: python, regression, linear-regression

I need a way to run a linear regression during a simulation in python. New X and y values come in, should be fitted and new coefficient estimates should be made. However, older values should get a lower weight.
Is there a package that can do this?

Comment: I think you're *"forgetting"* to ask a question...

Comment: @jonrsharpe  I think you should be able to infer that I need a package that does the described.

Comment: questions regarding finding an external tool/library are not welcome in SO; you are supposed to ask specific programming question, not a googling request.

Comment: @DavoudTaghawi-Nejad I didn't infer as much based on the fact that your rep suggests you should already know that package recommendations are off-topic. And part of asking a good question is making sure nobody has to infer anything!

Answer (score 1):

Short answer here, perhaps more an idea than a solution.

Have you tried [`scipy.optimize.curve_fit`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html) ?

It would do the fitting, but you would still have to code yourself the lower-weightening of the old values before passing it through the `absolute_sigma` parameter.